# Advice on making a threaded comment system in Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-models

I'm in the middle of making my Django commenting system. What i've done so far is:

- AJAX initial comments (parent comment appended without page refresh/saved to database)
- Django initial comments (able to render the parent comments above after page refresh)
- AJAX 1st reply (1st reply appended without page refresh/saved to database)

Now this is where i'm up to. As I want to have a threaded (endless) comment system where users can continuously reply to each other, I want to have a clear outlook of how I will do this before I start. My `Comment` model looks like this:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    destination = models.CharField(default='1', max_length=12, blank=True)
    parent_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    comment_text = models.TextField(max_length=350, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment_text
```

My AJAX call looks like this:

```
var str = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
var path = str.split("/")[4];

$('.comment_form').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var c = $(this).find('.comment_text').val()

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/user_comment/',
    data: {
        text: $(this).find('.comment_text').val(),
        id: path,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
},
    success: function(data) {
            $('.commentsContainer hr').prepend("<div class='comment_div'><div class='left_comment_div'>" +
                <h3><a href='#' class='username'>" + data.username +
                "</a></h3><p>" + data.text +
                "</p><a href='#'><span class='comment_delete'>x</span></a></div>");
        }

});

});
```

comments template

```
<div class="commentsContainer">
    <form action="" class="comment_form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ comment.comment_text|add_class:"comment_text" }}
        {{ comment.id }}
        <input type="submit" value="Comment" class="comment_submit">
    </form>
    <hr>
    {% for i in comment_list %}
        <div class='comment_div' data-comment_id="{{ i.id }}">
            <div class="left_comment_div">
                <div class="username_and_votes">
                    <h3><a class='username_foreign'>{{ i.user }}</a></h3>
                </div>
                <br>
                <p>{{ i.comment_text }}</p>
            </div>

                <a class="reply">reply</a><a class="cancel_comment">cancel</a>
                <span><a class="comment_delete" data-comment_id="{{ i.id }}">x</a></span>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

and here's my view:

```
def user_comment(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        comment = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        ajax_comment = request.POST.get('text')
        id = request.POST.get('id')

        if comment.is_valid():
            comment = Comment.objects.create(comment_text=ajax_comment, destination=id, user=request.user)
            comment.save()
            username = str(request.user)
            return JsonResponse({'text': ajax_comment,'username': username, 'id': comment.id})
```

Now I also started to try make the replies, but I probably didn't go about it the right way so feel free to disregard the following code as there's probably a better way. With the jQuery front end for the reply I had to make a seperate function as using the same function wasn't working. And I also had to make an `onclick` to make it work. So when a user clicks the reply button it clones the initial `comment_form` and appends it after the comment they're replying to:

```
$('.reply').on('click', function(e) {
    var clone = $('.comment_form').clone();
    parent_id = $(this).closest('.comment_div').data('comment_id');
    $(this).closest('.comment_div').after(
        clone
    );
    clone.addClass('reply_comment_form').removeClass('comment_form');
    clone.attr('onclick', 'reply_comment()');
    clone.data('comment_id', parent_id);

    $(this).next().css('display', 'inline-block');
    $(this).css('display', 'none');

});
```

// then when they submit the actual reply comment:

```
function reply_comment() {
    $('.reply_comment_form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        parent_id = $('.reply_comment_form').data('comment_id');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/comment_reply/',
            data: {
                reply_text: $(this).find('.comment_text').val(),
                parent_id: parent_id,
                id: path,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('.reply_comment_form').replaceWith("<div class='comment_div new_comment'><div class='left_comment_div'>" +
                "<h3><a href='#' class='username'>" + data.username +
                "</a></h3> + data.reply_text +
                "</p><a href='#'><span class='comment_delete'>x</span></a></div>");
                $('.new_comment').css({
                    'width': '72%',
                    'margin': '0 70 10 0',
                    'float': 'right',
                });
                 $('.new_comment').next().css('clear', 'both');
                 $('.new_comment').prev().find('.cancel_comment').css('display', 'inline-block')
                     .find('.cancel_comment').css('display', 'inline-block');
            }

        });


    });
}
```

reply view:

```
def comment_reply(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        comment = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        reply_text = request.POST.get('reply_text')
        id = request.POST.get('id')
        parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')

        if comment.is_valid():
            comment = Comment.objects.create(comment_text=reply_text, destination=id, user=request.user, parent_id=parent_id)
            comment.save()
            username = str(request.user)
            return JsonResponse({'reply_text': reply_text, 'username': username})
```

I've made the `parent_id` of the 1st replies to equal the `comment.id` of the original comment. But as I said linking these like this is probably not the best way, so how exactly do I link a comment and its replies? Do I make a another field in the `Comment` model? Could I somehow make a ForeignKey to reference back to the same `Comment` model? And how does it work in the template, in terms of rendering the replies of replies, becauses it's continuous. 
Advice apprecatied.

Answer (score 0):

> Could I somehow make a ForeignKey to reference back to the same
>   Comment model?

```
class Comment(models.Model):
     parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children')
     text = models.TextField(max_length=350, blank=True)
```

> And how does it work in the template, in terms of rendering the
>   replies of replies, becauses it's continuous

You can do something like this: make template `comment.html`.

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    <p>{{ comment.text }}</p>
    {% if comment.children %}
        {% include "comment.html" with comments=comment.children %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But you should do prefetch in your view to make less queries. I'm not sure how to do it for any depth. But for predefined depth it can be done like this: `Comment.objects.prefetch_related('children__children__children')`